How do I change the background colour of a class at midnight everyday rather than by a user event
Currently I have a piece of code that changes the background colour of a class every 24 hours. However if a user refreshes the page, the 24 hour cycle starts from the beginning – so they would only see the colour change if they stayed on the page for 24 hours without refreshing.
Instead I want the background colour to change every 24 hours at midnight, regardless of a user event.
Here is my code as it stands:
<script>

const bgColor = ["#DA6F33", "#33B2dA", "#66BD9E", "#667FBD"];
const backgroundSection = document.querySelector(".twofirst");
let i = 0;

function changeColor() {
  backgroundSection.style.backgroundColor = bgColor[i];
  i = (i + 1) % bgColor.length;
};

setInterval(changeColor, 86400000);

</script>


just implement a clock alarm function, set alarm at every day 00:00:00. then alarm function trigger changeColor() function.

Triggering an interval on page load doesn't look like a good solution, I see two alternatives here:

Calculate the background color at backend and include it in all the server response
Generate an index according to the system date

I'm going to propose a solution based on the second option.
First of all, let's calculate the number of days from the start of the year:
const start = new Date(date.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
const diff = date - start;
const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
const dayOfYear = Math.floor(diff / oneDay);

Then we can calculate an index just using the modulo operator (%):
const todayIndex = dayOfYear % 4;

If you want, you can shorten the function like this (I had a bit of fun):
const todayIndex = (Date.now() - new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 0)) / 86400000 % 4 | 0

Then just trigger an interval each minute to check if the date changed:
const bgColor = ["#DA6F33", "#33B2dA", "#66BD9E", "#667FBD"];
setInterval(() => {
      const todayIndex = (Date.now() - new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 0)) / 86400000 % 4 | 0;
      const todayBgColor = bgColor[todayIndex];
      // Apply the bg color
     
}, 60 * 1000);


Thanks for your answer @Christian, how do I make sure this background colour change is applied to the class: '.twofirst'?
